# Ruby mail script getting 550 No such domain at this location (Net::SMTPFatalError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I have a rails app that needs to use our organization's SMTP server, and I am trouble shooting this issue with the following script...

```
require 'mail'

options = {
    :address => 'barracuda.myorg.edu',
    :port => 25,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, options
end

Mail.deliver do
       to 'name@myorg.edu'
     from 'ada@myorg.edu'
  subject 'testing sendmail'
     body 'testing sendmail'
end
```

I am running this script from my rails server, and the script above works and does send mail successfully through our smtp server. However, it will only send messages that end in myorg.edu. If I try to send an email to a yahoo or gmail address, I get the error...

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:948:in `check_response': 550 No such domain at this location (Net::SMTPFatalError)
```

Is there some other option I should be setting in my script, or is this an issue in the smtp server side?

Comment: looks like a firewall issue here, look at this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/10196cda-aa70-41b1-816b-a6e22afb325d/550-no-such-domain-at-this-location?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaging

Comment: That worked bj, thanx. I forward that on to my network admin and fixed it.